# LINQ: Group by months quarter

Tags: c#, linq, linq-group

I would like to Group values by month quarter.
Supposing I have the following month quarters:

```
Month Range      Quarter Name
7->9             Q1
10->12           Q2
1->3             Q3
4->6             Q4
```

I want my results in linq to be grouped by Quarter based on Month number.
How can I achieve this in linq?

Answer (score 4):

Try this using [DateTime.Month](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var query = data.GroupBy(item => ((item.DateTimeProperty.Month - 1) / 3));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group by

`(dateTime.Month-1)/3`